# Comparing a file with a reference file with Python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I created fictional Data Frames that comprehends my doubt.

I have two excel spreadsheets that I want to compare, containing the data as follows:

**DataFrame to compare**

| Product ID | Color | Brand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Red | Nike |
| A | Red | Nike |
| A | Red | Addidas |
| A | Purple | Nike |
| A | Red | Nike |
| B | Yellow | CK |
| B | Yellow | CK |
| B | Yellow | CK |
| B | Yellow | CK |
| B | Yellow | CK |
| C | Green | Puma |
| C | Green | Puma |
| C | Green | Puma |
| C | Green | Nike |
| C | Green | Puma |

**Reference DataFrame**

| Product ID | Color | Brand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Red | Nike |
| B | Yellow | CK |
| C | Green | Puma |

**Expected Output**

| Product ID | Color | Brand | Validation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Red | Nike | Ok |
| A | Red | Nike | Ok |
| A | Red | Addidas | Not Ok |
| A | Purple | Nike | Not Ok |
| A | Red | Nike | Ok |
| B | Yellow | CK | Ok |
| B | Yellow | CK | Ok |
| B | Yellow | CK | Ok |
| B | Yellow | CK | Ok |
| B | Yellow | CK | Ok |
| C | Green | Puma | Ok |
| C | Green | Puma | Ok |
| C | Green | Puma | Ok |
| C | Green | Nike | Not Ok |
| C | Green | Puma | Ok |

**Packages I am using for previous analysis:** pandas, openpyxl

1.

My question here is: How to compare files with different number of
rows? I have five samples of A, that should be compared with one
unique row of the reference file. I couldn't write an iteration
because the counter will be different for each file. I was trying this for comparing the color column first:

```
for i in range(2, ref.max_row+1):  
   cell_obj_1 = ref.cell(row=i, column=1)
   for n range(2, Compare_file.max_row+1):
     cell_obj_2 = Compare_file.cell(row=j, column=1)
        while(cell_obj_1.value == cell_obj_2.value):
            if(Compare_file.cell(row=J+1, column=2).value==(ref.cell(row=I+1, column=2)).value):
                print('Ok')
            else:
                print('Not Ok')
```

`ref` = Reference DataFrame

`Compare_file` = DataFrame to Compare

I just printed for now but my interest is to create a new column in Compare file.

Comment: I don't know why but 2 of 3 tables are messy!! :(

Comment: You need a blank line before the table.

Comment: `df.apply` may work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your problem, you have a reference dataframe which contains correct product information and you want to compare this reference data against a second dataframe.  In the second dataframe you want to insert a new column which indicates the result of this evaluation.
So Given the reference dataframe df_ref as shown:

```
Product Color   Brand
0   A   Red Nike
1   B   Yellow  CK
2   C   Green   Puma
```

You want to compare the reference data against the dataframe df given below:

```
Product Color   Brand
0   A   Red Nike
1   A   Red Nike
2   A   Red Addidas
3   A   Purple  Nike
4   A   Red Nike
5   B   Yellow  CK
6   B   Yellow  CK
7   B   Yellow  CK
8   B   Yellow  CK
9   B   Yellow  CK
10  C   Green   Puma
11  C   Green   Puma
12  C   Green   Puma
13  C   Green   Nike
14  C   Green   Puma
```

create a comparfunction:

```
def compareFrames(dx: pd.DataFrame, dref: pd.DataFrame) ->list:
    rslt = []
    print(dx.shape[0])
    for i in range(dx.shape[0]):
        dx_data = dx.iloc[i].values
        dref_data = dref[dref['Product'] == dx_data[0]].values[0]
        if dref_data[1] ==dx_data[1] and dref_data[2] == dx_data[2]:
            rslt.append('OK')
        else:
            rslt.append('Not OK')
    return rslt
```

Which when used as follows:

```
df['Check'] = compareFrames(df, df_ref)
```

Yields:

```
    Product Color   Brand   Check
0   A   Red Nike    OK
1   A   Red Nike    OK
2   A   Red Addidas Not OK
3   A   Purple  Nike    Not OK
4   A   Red Nike    OK
5   B   Yellow  CK  OK
6   B   Yellow  CK  OK
7   B   Yellow  CK  OK
8   B   Yellow  CK  OK
9   B   Yellow  CK  OK
10  C   Green   Puma    OK
11  C   Green   Puma    OK
12  C   Green   Puma    OK
13  C   Green   Nike    Not OK
14  C   Green   Puma    OK
```

Comment: It works pretty good for this example, however my database is a little bit bigger with one column similar to Product ID, and 12 features instead of 2 (color and brand). I tried to adapt to my real situation, and I got this Traceback: IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: Can't possibly help you without seeing the code which produced the error.  But I can guess that you are trying to index a variable which is a unitary value or None.

Comment: Also, can I access and append the Not Ok cell along with the result list? Another question, can I check column by column? Is it changing shape[0] to shape[1]?

Comment: Not sure I understand your questions.  What do you mean by access the 'Not Ok' cell along with the result list?  Are you asking if you can append the rslt list contents at the time you detect a 'Not OK' condition?   I also don't understand your question related to checking column by column, since the requirement is to identify rows that don't satisfy all required conditions.  How do you envision this working?  It would also be quite a bit less efficient.

Comment: Something just like thi: product = [] # for j in range(dref.shape[1]):
#         for i in range(0,nrow,5):
#             if(dx.iat[i,j]==dx.iat[i+1,j] and dx.iat[i+1,j]==dx.iat[i+2,j] and dx.iat[i+2,j]==dx.iat[i+3,j] and dx.iat[i+3,j]==dx.iat[i+4,j]):
#                 producti.at[i,j]='Ok'
#             else:
#                 product.at[i,j]='Not Ok

Comment: can you edit your question with an example of what you are looking for, or better yet ask a new question related to this, since SO typically requires each question be related to a single issue.  This seems like a new issue to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have this in a database, do the work in the database if you can.
The basic check is whether colour and brand are of the allowed combination.

```
Allowed = (("Red", "Nike"), ("Yellow", "CK"), ("Green", "Puma"))

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=2, max_col=3):
    values = (c.value for c in row)
    validation = values in Allowed and "OK" or "Not OK"
    check = row[0].offset(column=1)
    check.value = validation
```

This is probably the quickest way if your data is in Excel, otherwise I think you can do it in a dataframe using a lambda function, or in a database.